# Node Application to run in a sub-folder under Apache

Tags: node.js, apache

I have a simple node/angular application and I would like it to run under a sub-folder of an apache/php application.

What I mean:

At the moment the node app runs under this url `http://www.mysite.com:8080` I need the application to run under `http://www.mysite.com/nodeapps/applicationName/index.html`

Do I need to change something in my apache configuration except moving the application under that folder?

The node app now is under `opt/applications/node/applicationName`

I am new to Node.js so please make sure that you explain your solution in details or else I am going to get even more confused :)

Answer (score 0):

Apache simply serves files. However, your node application will also serve files without the need of an extra server. So you don't want your node.js files to be in a folder served by Apache (this will make the source code public which you probably don't want in most cases). Instead, the way to go is to run node.js on a custom port (like the above http://www.example.com:8080) and to redirect from apache to that port like so:

```
RewriteRule /nodeapps/applicationName/(.*) http://localhost:8080/$1 [P]
```